# Better to make SKShapeNode or SKSpriteNode in spritekit game?

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode, frame-rate, skshapenode

I make a game in spritekit, so make a some things in SKShapeNode and of course use SKSpriteNode's in my game.
Which is better for fps and good for optimization of this game using SKShapeNode's or SKSpriteNode's?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SKSpriteNode` will be more performant. `SKShapeNode` has issues with it such as memory leaking.

Comment: Thank you, Mobile Ben :)

Comment: Any official source for this?